# Test with multipage methods (Page Objects) - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, junit, automation

I have the following problem:

I can only call the method (.confirmaLogin) from the same page (class).
Why can't I add methods from other pages?

First page (class):

```
                public class loginSIGE {
    public WebDriver browser;
    public loginSIGE(WebDriver browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }
    public loginSIGE confirmaLogin() {
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat\"]")).click();
        return new telaPrincipal(browser);
    }
```

Second page:

```
public class telaPrincipal extends loginSIGE {
    public telaPrincipal(WebDriver browser) {
        super(browser);
    }
    public telaPrincipal cliqueDenuncia() {
        browser.findElement(By.linkText("Denuncias")).click();
        return new telaDenuncia (browser);
    }
```

Test:

```
  public void acesso() {
        new loginSIGE(browser)
               .confirmaLogin();
```

I can't add the second page method!

I look forward and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using without extending from the loginsige class.

Comment: I did not understand!
Could you give an example, please?

Comment: As you used the "public class telaPrincipal extends loginSIGE" in your code try using "public class telaPrincipal" - do not extend from loginSIGE class.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. =////
And the correct would not be the following pages add the extends?

Comment: Someone?!?! rs. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can anybody help me?
rsrs

Comment: Hello?! rsrsrs!